# Command Line code without any addon to unzip a .zip file

Tags: command-line, zip, unzip

I have no idea about command line scripts. 
I checked the few already existing threads on the similar topic however I could not find a thread which mentions the exact code to unzip the file. 
I have found the a code where Fk8pwu47g.zip is my file which I need to unzip
                  **for /R "C:\Users\sneshah\Desktop\2. ISM" %I in ("Fk8pwu47g.zip") do ("%ProgramFiles(x86)%\WinZip\winzip32.exe" Fk8pwu47g -y -o"%%~dpnI" "%%~fI")**

but it throws errors as below:

> Action: Add (and replace) files  Include subfolders: no  Save full
>   path: no no files were found for -y that match your selection
>   criteria. no files were found for -o"%C:\Users\sneshah\Desktop\2. that
>   match your selection criteria. no files were found for Fk8pwu47g""
>   that match your selection criteria. Irrecoverable Error: Bad or
>   incomplete option for the operation.

Answer (score 0):

We achieved the requirement using a powershell script to unzip file.
Here is the code

---

```
$src = "C:\Desktop\InputFile\"
$dest = "C:\Desktop\OutputFile\"

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
$zps = Get-ChildItem $src -Filter *.zip

foreach ($zp IN $zps)
{
$foldernames = Get-ChildItem $dest
$newfolders = $dest + $zp

$all = $src + $zp
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory($all, $newfolders)
}
```